# Files uploaded in SharePoint Online differ from original

Tags: excel, file-upload, online

currently using [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) to upload files into SharePoint Online instances, mainly Excel files (xlsx and xlsm). They are uploaded and downloaded just fine, but now I am noticing that uploaded the Excel files are different from the sources: When downloading that file and comparing it with original they differ:

```sh
diff original.xlsm downloaded.xlsm

Binary files original.xlsm and downloaded.xlsm differ
```

It is also evident that the file changed when I open it from SharePoint's Excel Online and I see I have lost some styles.

**Downloaded file is not corrupt** since it opens in Excel.

So is this a normal behavior for SharePoint Online? What could I do if I want to SharePoint Online to not modify the uploaded file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior due to property demotion/promotion. When an Office document is uploaded, the parser will add additional metadata to it. In SPO, the parser cannot be disabled.